# importing C written binary files into Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binary, binaryfiles

I've read the post "Read and write from/to a binary file in Matlab" but I still have doubts. I have a binary file of long double values created with fwrite in C and in Matlab I'm using

```
fid = fopen('vz3.dat', 'r')
mydata = fread(fid, 'double')
```

where vz3.dat is my file. But I'm getting garbage values in Matlab. According to

```
[cinfo, maxsize, ordering] = computer
```

in Matlab, my computer is a little-endian system (byte ordering system). Any suggestions?

By the way, does a binary file necessarily have to end in .bin .I'm using the .dat extension. Is it ok to do so?

Thanks a lot

Comment: From my experience, binary files can end in just about anything you want. I use .raw for the some of my data processing. Using .dat or .bin would probably help avoid confusion though.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why subconsciously I went for dat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a file with little endian, use

```
fid = fopen('vz3.dat','r','l');
```

It doesn't matter what the file is called, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working. I've used: format long; fid = fopen('vz3.dat', 'r','l'); mydata = fread(fid, 'double'). Please see my other post "Binary files printing and desired precision". It says Matlab can handle double but not long double.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: `long double` isn't a standard precision name.  Presumably you mean the representation used by your C++ compiler for the (implementation-dependent) C++ data type `long double`?  Need to know more about your toolchain, but the usual suspects are 64-bit IEEE and 80-bit x87 formats.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to use a file handle opened elsewhere, you can also use the `machineformat` parameter to `fread` (which is optional).

The documentation is available [on the MathWorks site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html).